# a general version of Lebesgue Domianted Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In Elias Stein's book, there's a proof of the Lebesgue Dom. Conv. Thm. and the idea is that if $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $|f_n| \leq g$, with $g$ integrable, we have to decompose the integral $\int |f_n-f|$ as

$$\int |f_n-f| = \int_{E} |f_n-f| + \int_{E^c}|f_n-f|, $$ with $E$ taken suitably such that both integrals are bounded by some given $\epsilon$.

More precisely, let $\epsilon>0$ so by a previous lemma there exists $N$ such that $\int_{E_N^c} g <\epsilon$, where $E_N=\{x: |x| \leq N, g(x)\leq N \}$.   Then the sequence of functions $f_n \chi_{E_N}$ converges to $f \chi_{E_N}$ and by the bounded conv. Thm  (the sequence is bounded by $N$),

$$\int_{E_N} |f_n-f| < \epsilon,$$ for $n$ large enough (we have our first bound).

For the second integral, we just have to see that $|f_n-f| \leq 2g$ and then $\int_{E^c}|f_n-f| \leq 2\int_{E_n^c} g < 2\epsilon$ (our second bound).

My question is how we can prove the Generalized version of the Thm based on this proof (the generalized version is replacing $g$ in the original one by a sequence $g_n \in L^1$, which still bounds $f_n$, and such that $g_n$ converges to some $g \in L^1$.

Comment: The answer is no. Else the domination hypothesis would be useless, because you could take $g_n = f_n$

Answer (score 0):

We can get the stronger DCT from Fatou's Lemma: Suppose $f_n$ are measurable on $X$ and $f_n \to f$ a.e. Suppose further that $g_n, g$ are measurable, $|f_n|\le g_n$ a.e., and $g_n \to g$ in $L^1.$ Then $f_n \to f$ in $L^1.$

Proof: Suppose not. Then for some $\epsilon>0, \int|f-f_{n_k}| > \epsilon$ along a subsequence. Along some further subsequence, still denoted by $n_k,$ we have $g_{n_k} \to g$ a.e. Note that because $|f_{n_k}|\le g_{n_k} \to g$ a.e., we have $|f|\le g$ a.e. This tells us each $g_{n_k}+g - |f_{n_k}-f|\ge 0.$ So we can use Fatou:

$$\int \liminf (g_{n_k}+g - |f_{n_k}-f|) \le \liminf \int (g_{n_k}+g - |f_{n_k}-f|).$$

The left side equals $\int 2g.$ The right side equals

$$ \int 2g -\limsup \int |f_{n_k}-f|.$$

It follows that $\limsup \int |f_{n_k}-f| = 0,$ contradicition.

Comment: So, by taking $g_n = |f_n|$, you're saying that the domination hypothesis is not necessary if $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$...

Comment: No, I'm saying exactly what I wrote. We are proving the conclusion of the DCT, namely that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1,$ but with weaker hypthoses.